# How can I get the length of each output line of grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am very new to bash scripting.
I have a network trace file I want to parse. Part of the trace file is (two packets):

```
    [continues...]
    +---------+---------------+----------+
    05:00:00,727,744   ETHER
    |0  
    |00|03|a0|09|5c|1c|00|10|07|df|a4|20|08|00|45|00|00|38|e7|55|

    +---------+---------------+----------+
    05:00:00,727,751   ETHER
    |0  
    |00|03|a0|09|5c|1c|00|10|07|df|a4|20|08|00|45|00|00|38|e7|56|00|00|3a|01|

    [continues...]
```

For each packet, I want to print the time stamp, and the length of the packet (the hex values coming on the next line after |0 header) so the output will look like:

```
    05:00:00.727744 20 bytes
    05:00:00.727751 24 bytes
```

I can get the line with time stamp and the packets separately using grep in bash:

```
times=$(grep  '..\:..\:' $fileName)
packets=$(grep  '..|..|' $fileName)
```

But I can't work with the separate output lines after that. The whole result is concatenated in the two variables "times" and "packets". How can I get the length of each packet?

P.S. a good reference that really explains how to do bash programming, rather than just doing examples would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you create that network trace? It is usually much easier to output the needed values directly in the first place instead of writing some verbose text and trying to parse that later.

Comment: @rici, thanks for the point. fixed

Comment: @michas, I downloaded it. didn't generate it myself.

Comment: You might want to check out awk (or perl or python, for that matter). For awk, take a look at the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), particularly the introductory chapter and then the chapter called "Practical awk programs". Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to do such things with your shell.

You want to write a real parser that understands the format to output the needed informations.

For a quick and dirty hack you can do something like that:

```
perl -wne 'print "$& " if /^\d\S*/; print split(/\|/)-2, " bytes\n" if /^\|..\|/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, with plain old shell...

You can get the length of the line like this:

```
line="|00|03|a0|09|5c|1c|00|10|07|df|a4|20|08|00|45|00|00|38|e7|55|"
wc -c<<<$line
62
```

There are sixty two characters in that line. Think of each character as `|00` where `00` can be any digit. In that case, there's an extra `|` on the end. Plus, the `wc -c` includes the `NL` on the end.

So, if we take the value of `wc -c`, and subtract 2, we get `60`. If we divide that by 3, we get `20` which is the number of characters.

Okay, now we need a little loop, figure out the various lines, and then parse them:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ ^[[:digit:]]{2} ]]
    then
        echo -n "${line% *}"
    elif [[ $line =~ ^\|[[:digit:]]{2} ]]
    then
        length=$(wc -c<<<$line)
        ((length-=2))
        ((length=length/3))
        echo "$length bytes"
    fi
done < test.txt
```

There a ***PURE BASH*** solution to your problems!

You're a beginning Bash programmer, and you have no idea what's going on...

Let's take this one step at a time:

A common way to loop through a file in BASH is using a `while read` loop. This combines the `while` with a `read`:

```
while read line
do
   echo "My line is '$line'"
done < test.txt
```

Each line in `test.txt` is being read into the `$line` shell variable.

Let's take the next one:

```
if [[ $line =~ ^[[:digit:]]{2} ]]
```

This is an `if` statement. Always use the `[[ ... ]]` brackets because they fix issues with the shell interpolating stuff. Plus, they have a bit more power.

The `=~` is a regular expression match. The `[[:digit:]]` matches any digit. The `^` anchors the regular expression to the beginning of the line, and `{2}` means I want exactly two of these. This says if I match a line that starts with two digits (which is your timestamp line), execute this `if` clause.

`${line% *}` is a pattern filter. The `%` says to match the (glob) smallest glob pattern to the right and filter it from my `$line` variable. I use this to remove the `ETHER` from my line. The `-n` tells `echo` not to do a NL.

Let's take my `elif` which is an else if clause.

```
elif [[ $line =~ ^\|[[:digit:]]{2} ]]
```

Again, I am matching a regular expression. This regular expression starts with (The `^`) a `|`. I have to put a backslash in front because `|` is a magical regular expression character and `\` kills the magic. It's now just a pipe. Then, that's followed by two digits. Note this skips `|0` but catches `|00`.

Now, we have to do some calculations:

```
length=$(wc -c<<<$line)
```

The `$(...)` say to execute the enclosed command and resubstitute it back in the line. The `wc -c` counts the characters and `<<<$line` is what we're counting. This gave us `62` characters. We have to subtract 2, then divide by 3. That's the next two lines:

```
((length-=2))
((length/=3))
```

The `((...))` allows me to do integer based math. The first subtracts 2 from `$length` and the next divides it by `3`. Now, I can echo this out:

```
echo "$length bytes"
```

And that's our pure Bash answer to this question.